# Удаление записей с таблицы

Tags: php, mysqli

Добрый день) Есть код, который отрисовует таблицу с БД и у него есть функция удаление записей с таблицы. Все вроде как-то работает, но при удалении записи, она удаляется не сразу, а только после обновления страницы. Можно ли как-то это исправить?

```
<?php

define(HOST, 'localhost');
define(USER, 'root');
define(PASSWORD, '');
define(DB_NAME, 'test');

$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_connect_error($link));

mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$query = "SELECT * FROM workers";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {       
    $mass[] = $row; 
}

$show = '<table border = "1">';

$show .= '<tr>'; 
foreach($mass[0] as $key => $val) { 
$show .= '<th>'.$key.'</th>'; 
} 

foreach ($mass as $value) {                 
    $show .= '<tr>';                                
    foreach ($value as $subvalue) {     
        $show .= '<td>'.$subvalue.'</td>';
    }
    $show .= '<td><a href="?del='.$value['id'].'">удалить</a></td>';
    $show .= '</tr>';
}

$show .= '</table>';

if(!empty($_GET['del'])){
    $queryDel = "DELETE FROM `workers` WHERE id=".$_GET['del'];
    mysqli_query($link, $queryDel) or die(mysqli_error($link));
 }
mysqli_close($link);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?=$show?>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: перенесите блок кода `if(_GET['del'])` в начало, до того как выбираются записи из таблицы. зы: обычно get-запросы не используются для удаления и изменения. задумайтесь, что будет если кто-то  напишет в качестве параметра `0 or 1=1`

Comment: @teran спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас небольшой недочет в логике работы: сначала вы запрашиваете данные по таблице, формируете ее вывод, затем удаляете строку и выводите на экран старый вывод, который был до того, как вы удалили строку.

Исправить легко: нужно лишь блок с удалением вынести наверх. Как то так:

```
<?php

define(HOST, 'localhost');
define(USER, 'root');
define(PASSWORD, '');
define(DB_NAME, 'test');

$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_connect_error($link));

mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if(!empty($_GET['del'])){
    $queryDel = "DELETE FROM `workers` WHERE id=".$_GET['del'];
    mysqli_query($link, $queryDel) or die(mysqli_error($link));
 }

$query = "SELECT * FROM workers";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {       
    $mass[] = $row; 
}

$show = '<table border = "1">';

$show .= '<tr>'; 
foreach($mass[0] as $key => $val) { 
$show .= '<th>'.$key.'</th>'; 
} 

foreach ($mass as $value) {                 
    $show .= '<tr>';                                
    foreach ($value as $subvalue) {     
        $show .= '<td>'.$subvalue.'</td>';
    }
    $show .= '<td><a href="?del='.$value['id'].'">удалить</a></td>';
    $show .= '</tr>';
}

$show .= '</table>';

mysqli_close($link);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?=$show?>
</body>

</html>
```